# QM API Rest use

Tags: java, rest, api, websphere

I'm wanting to use the QM REST API to gather this information so that I can use it inside my own java application.

Really this is all i am looking to do with the API/rest call:
[image]
Really this is all i am looking to do with the API/rest call:
enter image description here

I've managed to get to the Test Suite Execution Records but still not the data i need. I just want to grab everything in that table.

Could you please let me know what API/REST calls I need to make in order to get the needed information?

Comment: Reworded what I am looking for so that maybe someone understands my issue better.

Comment: Reworded again in hopes someone knows the answer.

Comment: Still looking for some assistance please.

Comment: Still no one knows?